# Why does the gem mysql2 fails to install when i try to install a version 0.3.x but successfully installs the version 0.4.x and above?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to ruby on rails and am trying to run an older project using gem mysql2 0.3.21. I cant change the gem version. I have already used "sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev" command and the error is still there.

[image]

Also when i use the command "sudo apt install libmariadb-dev" the bundle is installed but the rake db:create gives error.

[image: error after the bundle runs]

Answer (score 1):

The ruby mysql client is infamously known to be very picky on which dynamic libraries you have installed in your system. So if your local mysql (even just the shared client dev package) is not 100% compatible with the expectations of the gem version, you will not be able to compile it.

I have personally had to switch between 0.3.15 and 0.3.21 because the mysql version in ubuntu (my machine) was only compatible with gem 0.3.21 and above (being MySQL 5.7), while the one on MacOS (the rest of the team) only with 0.3.15 (it was MySQL 5.5).

To make your gem compile you need to have MySQL 5.7 dev packages, and not 8.0+. Once it's compiled, you can switch back to the current version (or even better, start the compatible version in a docker container).